# is there any way to resize image according to the size and resolution of the image which user send to react js chat app

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, image-resizing

I am working on a chat application in which i am using socket.io if the user send any images then the size of image and resolution of image is different according to image which is sent in the chat. So i want to resize it so that it can fit in the message body is there any way to do that? or any other suggestion to resize or something.....

```
this.socket.on('RECEIVE_FILE', function(data){
        addFile(data);
    });
    const addFile = data=>{
        console.log("File data",data);
        console.log("file : ",data.file,data.fileName,data.author,data.author_user_id);
        this.setState({messages : [...this.state.messages,data]});
        console.log("this.state.file : ",this.state.file);
        if(this.refs.canvas!==undefined)
        {
            const ctx = this.refs.canvas.getContext('2d');
            let canvas_width = 300;
            let canvas_height = 300;
            let image = new Image();
            image.src = data.file;
            image.onload = ()=> {
                ctx.drawImage(image,
                    0,0,image.width,image.height,
                    0,0,canvas_width,canvas_height
                );
            }
            this.setState({fileUpload:''});}
        }
```

I am not sure about this code but i have done this so far it resize or crop the image and draw it using canvas but as the size of the image is different for every image it works for some not each and every

Comment: Could you please provide the code that you've already tried so we can offer suggestions?

Comment: I've updated the question with code @MichaelMcQuade